# TinyMCE: Alignment not working with forced_root_block

Tags: tinymce

Any idea why the alignment buttons aren't working here? When you click any of the alignment buttons, they then get deselected automatically.

If you remove forced_root_block, it works

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gYfaab/1

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.5/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".content",
 inline: true,
 forced_root_block: false,
    toolbar: "alignleft aligncenter alignright"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <div class="content"  style="border:1px solid grey;height: 200px;">This is my content.</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: I think this is more of an issue with inline editing ... if you turn that off it seems to work.  If you think this is a bug I would open a ticket in the TinyMCE GitHub issue tracker:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues